# How do I set a UDP socket to non-blocking in QNX

Tags: c++, sockets, udp, qnx

I'm coding a UDP datagram receiver in C++ on the QNX operating system and I want to perform non-blocking recvfrom() calls.

The [QNX man page on recvfrom()](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.3.0SP3/neutrino/lib_ref/r/recvfrom.html) suggests that I somehow can put a socket in a non-blocking mode using ioctl(). Unfortunately, the [man page on ioctl()](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.3.0SP3/neutrino/lib_ref/i/ioctl.html) isn't much of a help.

Can anybody tell me about the arguments I have to pass to ioctl() to set the socket to non-blocking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`ioctl`](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.4.0/neutrino/lib_ref/i/ioctl.html) doc for QNX 6.4.0 has a bit more info:

> **FIONBIO**
>
> Set or clear non-blocking I/O

The `ioctl` call should look something like this:

```
int on = 1;
ioctl(fd, FIONBIO, &on);
```

Comment: It works. Thank you. Looks like Google did not point me to the best documentation.